# Spring 4 mvc загрузка файла используя @ModelAtribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. Изучаю спринг, пытаюсь загрузить фото.
Есть модель типа:

```
class Photo
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] photo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

Когда в форме присутствует `enctype=multipart/form-data` и в контролере вызывается геттер `getPhoto()`, то получаемый файл `null`, если в форме не ставить `multipart` то все работает, но загружается не файл а его имя.

Я так понимаю в контролере нужно получить объект типа Multipart? Вопрос как это сделать если в модели объявлен `byte[]` для последующей записи в БД.

Пробовал совместно с `@ModelAtribute` использовать `@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile file`, но так значение получить не удалось.

В какую сторону еще посмотреть, чтоб все таки загрузить именно файл а не его имя?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Отсутствовало переопределение следующего метода, для поддержки Servlet 3

```
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration)
{
}
```